# Les nombreux sens de « messed up » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, choix-de-mot, demande-de-mot

Comment se traduirait « messed up » dans ces cas ?

> "This guy is really messed up." (went through a lot, had bad
>   experiences)
>  "My computer got messed up, sorry.” (ruined, messy,
>   in a bad state)
>  “That’s so messed up what you said!” (very wrong,
>   fucked up, evil, rude)

Je connais « paumé » et « tordu » peut-être, mais c’est tout.

Answer (score 3):

Au Québec (surtout), on peut employer les adjectifs [*fucké*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuck%C3%A9) (dérangé, brisé, fichu, bizarre), [*magané*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maganer) (endommagé, abîmé) et [*capoté*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/capot%C3%A9) (fou, inattendu), selon le contexte ; c'est informel, populaire :

> *Ce gars-là il est vraiment fucké, magané*. [*de la vie*<sup>1</sup> adds along the lines of what you explained]
>   *Mon ordi était fucké, capout/kaput, désolé.* (aussi l'emprunt à l'allemand, *[capout](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/capout#fr), kaput*)
>   *C'est vraiment fucké, capoté ce que t'as dit.* [weird, twisted ; [*malade*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/malade#Fran%C3%A7ais) could be extraordinary or sick]
>  
>   *Ça n'a vraiment [pas d'allure](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_pas_avoir_d%E2%80%99allure)/pas de [bon sens](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bon_sens#fr) ce que tu as dit.* [unsound, shocking]

<sub><sup>1</sup> À ne pas confondre avec la locution [*de la vie*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_la_vie) (jamais) en français plus régulier ; ici on veut dire *par la vie*.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

"This guy is really messed up." : *Ce type est vraiment dérangé.*

"My computer got messed up, sorry.” : *Mon ordinateur est détraqué, désolé.*

“That’s so messed up what you said!” : *Ce que vous dites est complètement pourri.* ou (colloquial)
 *"C'est tordu ce que tu dis."*

« Paumé » est de la langue vulgaire et sauf avec des jeunes qui parlent vulgairement, cela fera mauvaise impression. De plus, « tordu » pourrait à la rigueur convenir du point de vue sens mais pas « paumé » jamais (As an adjective it means "lost").

Answer (score 1):

"This guy is really messed up."

> Ce mec, il est à l'ouest grave.

"My computer got messed up, sorry.”

> Mon PC, il déconne de ouf, désolé.

“That’s so messed up what you said!”

> C'est trop n'importe quoi, ce que t'as dis.